# How are Huey, Dewey, and Louie related to Scrooge?

Tags: ducktales

In Duck Tales, Huey, Dewey, and Louie call Scrooge McDuck, "Uncle Scrooge".
They call Donald "Uncle Donald" and Donald calls Scrooge, "Uncle Scrooge".

How are they actually related to one another?

Comment: Seeing the response on this question, I think a lot of folks here are the kids from late 80s/early 90s :-)

Comment: This is about a comic character so much that both the answers rely on information only given in the comic books.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

According to the [Disney Wiki](http://disney.wikia.com/wiki/Donald%27s_Nephews)

> Huey, Dewey and Louie are the sons of Donald's sister [Della Duck](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KiBNE.gif)

Which means they really are Donald's nephews, and as mentioned on the sidebar on the [Donald Duck article](http://disney.wikia.com/wiki/Donald_Duck), Scrooge McDuck is Donald's uncle, though really he's his **uncle-in-law** as this relationship is through his wife's mother, [Hortense McDuck](http://disney.wikia.com/wiki/Hortense_McDuck), who is the sister to Scrooge.

This means Huey, Dewey and Louie are Scrooge McDuck's **grand-nephews** (his sister's grandchildren) and he is their **great-uncle** (grandmother's brother), as you can see from the infographic below.

It's likely they just went with "Uncle" for convenience, as most people aren't familiar with the term great-uncle.

[image: Relations]

Comment: The duck family tree : http://duckman.pettho.com/tree/l_us.jpg

Comment: For what it's worth, I think most people would choose "Uncle" over "Great-uncle" when referring to someone they interact with on a regular basis.  Especially since "Uncle" can also be used for "unrelated close friend of my parents who I see frequently"

Comment: @MrShibby - Wow! I haven't seen this in a loooong time! I've always loved how the triplets' dad's name is covered up.

Comment: IIRC Scrooge doesn't like to be called great-uncle because it makes him feel as old as he actually is.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a duck family tree that shows how Huey, Dewey, Louie, Scrooge and Donald are related:

reff: [What the duck](http://www.digestivepyrotechnics.com/2012/06/what-duck.html)

[image]

[image: Full Family Tree]